# Is it possible to combine tag URL with category URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need a tag URL that looks like

`site/category/my-tag` or `site/category/sub-category/my-tag`

Is it possible to make this?

Comment: if you want to convert tags to categories
it is under tools > import, called Categories and Tags Converter

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the slug path for your custom tag:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category/sub-category/my-tag', 'hierarchical' => true ) );
```

Add this to your custom taxonomy tag.